# Replace a string in nodejs, example id: with _xid:

Tags: node.js, regexp-replace

I need to replace all id: from a string to _xid: tried, use

```
string.replace (/id:/g, '_xid:')
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you show the sample string for which this did not work? Also assuming u want to replace `id:` with `_xid:` and not `/id:/` with `/_xid:/` although it is same case.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function (search, replacement) {
    const target = this
    return target.replace(new RegExp(search, 'g'), replacement)
}

string.replaceAll('id', '_xid')
```

Comment: replace /id:/ by /_xid:/

Comment: Why do you want to replace the outer /...:/ with same /...:/ ?
You are changing the string 'id' into '_idx', right?

Comment: there are other id's in the string, I want to change only those with id:

Answer (score 0):

`string.replace(/id:/g, '/_xid:/')`
can't find anything as the '/' chars are considered the opening and closing of a regex.

Try

```js
str.replace(/\/id:\//g, '/_xid:/')
```

to escape '\' char.

Comment: can you send a sample string and the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

```js
let text = 'first id: and second id:'
text = text.replace(/id:/g, '_xid:');
console.log(text)
```

Comment: I absolutely don't see any difference with the OP's code. Could you highlight it?